# Facebook Graph API: The Comments API does not return comment made by another user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, c#-4.0

Today, I noticed that the Facebook Graph API query does not return the comments made by another user.
Suppose, UserA created a postX and another userB add a comment on this post. Now, When I make the following api to get posts and comments of userA by passing the access_token of userA, the comments of userB is not returned.

{user_id}?fields=id,name,link,feed.fields(id,message_tags,source,with_tags,to,from,created_time,type,privacy,place,message,story,description,link,attachments,properties,caption,name,comments.fields(id,from,message,attachment,created_time,message_tags).order(reverse_chronological).limit(5)).since(1516531598).limit(3)

I have searched on the Facebook API change [logs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes/#ig-gapi-4-24) if there is any changes regarding the comment API but could not find any.

Answer (score 2):

After searching Facebook blogs, it is found that it is a purposeful change made by Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/05/01/facebook-login-updates-further-protect-privacy/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If i pass in my own post id, i am getting comments but not the user who commented.